# What does exception during Kafka Stream aggregate mean?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm writing an application in Kafka v1.0 Streams, and encountering a strange runtime problem when I try to run the application.  The application, simplified, looks like:

```
KStream< String, ValueClass > stream = ...;
KGroupedStream< String, ValueClass > groupedStream = stream.groupByKey();
KTable< String, ValueClass > aggregatedTable = 
    groupedStream
    .aggregate( ()-> new ValueClass(),  // initializer
                ( string, invalue, aggvalue ) -> { 
                     ValueClass aggResult = f( invalue, aggvalue );
                     return aggResult; }, // aggregator
                Materialized.with( Serdes.String(), ValueClassSerde )
              );
```

I've confirmed with a `print( Printed.toSysOut() )` operation that the input KStream looks like I expect, and adding the `groupByKey()` the application still works, but when I add the aggregation operation, I get a runtime error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to ValueClass
```

I've gone over the program several times and it still looks reasonable to me, and I can't figure out what in the processing is trying to cast a `String` to an instance of `ValueClass`.

Can you please explain what the error message is telling me, and what I need to do to fix the problem?

---

Next problem:  I modified the code above, adding a step to convert the aggregation output table to a stream and printing that:

```
KStream< String, ValueClass > stream = ...;
KGroupedStream< String, ValueClass > groupedStream = stream.groupByKey();
KTable< String, ValueClass > aggregatedTable = 
    groupedStream
    .aggregate( ()-> new ValueClass(),  // initializer
                ( string, invalue, aggvalue ) -> { 
                     ValueClass aggResult = f( invalue, aggvalue );
                     return aggResult; }, // aggregator
                Materialized.with( Serdes.String(), ValueClassSerde )
              );
aggregatedTable.toStream().print( Printed.toSysOut() );
```

The program runs, but nothing comes out.  Moreover, when I run under the Eclipse debugger and put a breakpoint inside the aggregation function `f`, execution never hits the breakpoint.

I've read something about KTable.toStream not outputting every result in order to save stream traffic; is that what's going on here, and is there any way to prevent it so that output gets flushed immediately?

Comment: Do you (potentially) change the `key` before calling `groupByKey()`? For example calling `map()`, even if your function does not modify the key?

Comment: Btw: you might be able simplify your code by using `reduce()` instead of `aggregation` as you don't change the type of the value.

Comment: Matthias, I think you identified the problem as a type confusion problem.   I changed the `groupBy` to use an explicit `Serialize.with( Serdes.String, ValueClassSerde)` and now the application works.  One question:  why wasn't this problem caught at compile time?   Was I stressing the type inference too much?

Comment: Egg on my face:   The problem was exceptions in serializer and deserializer for ValueClass.  Once fixed, application now appears to run successfully.